# Sum certain values of a list inside a dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, sum

I have this dictionary with a list of values on it:

```
d = { 
    '1751': [70.0, 43.5, 45.3, 56.4, 60.7, 50.7, 66.3, 59.8, 23.5, 23.2, 28.5, 44.0], 
    '1752': [35.0, 50.0, 71.0, 59.3, 59.7, 39.6, 78.4, 29.3, 27.1, 46.6, 37.6, 40.0], 
    '1753': [44.0, 32.0, 45.7, 38.0, 36.0, 31.7, 22.0, 39.0, 28.0, 25.0, 20.0, 6.7], 
    '1754': [0.0, 3.0, 1.7, 13.7, 20.7, 26.7, 18.8, 12.3, 8.2, 24.1, 13.2, 4.2], 
    '1755': [10.2, 11.2, 6.8, 6.5, 0.0, 0.0, 8.6, 3.2, 17.8, 23.7, 6.8, 20.0], 
    '1756': [12.5, 7.1, 5.4, 9.4, 12.5, 12.9, 3.6, 6.4, 11.8, 14.3, 17.0, 9.4], 
    '1757': [14.1, 21.2, 26.2, 30.0, 38.1, 12.8, 25.0, 51.3, 39.7, 32.5, 64.7, 33.5], 
    '1758': [37.6, 52.0, 49.0, 72.3, 46.4, 45.0, 44.0, 38.7, 62.5, 37.7, 43.0, 43.0], 
    '1759': [48.3, 44.0, 46.8, 47.0, 49.0, 50.0, 51.0, 71.3, 77.2, 59.7, 46.3, 57.0]
     }
```

Every  key-value represents  a year  and  each year has a list of twelve values , that represents each month of the year (the first value is the value for January, the second one is the value for February, the third one is the value for March,..).

The user is going to be ask to insert a beginning year a beginning month and a ending year and a ending month:

```
print("Begining year")
year1 = input()
print("Begining month")
month1 = input()


print("Ending year")
year2 = input()
print("Ending month")
month2 = input()
```

I wish to get users' input and go through the dictionary in order to sum all the values listed between the period of time determined by the user and print the total value.

Comment: What will user input? Month no or month name?

Comment: can you add the code you have so far?

Comment: it will be the month number

Comment: like 1, 2, 3 ... 12? right?

Comment: I just basically have this. I read a text file and I created a dictionary with the information on it. And then I am asking the user for the year and month of beginning and end. The next step is to sum the values during that period of time, but I don't really know how to do it, so I can't show you much more about my code, sorry. Any type of help will be welcome. Thanks a lot.

Comment: yes, like 1, 2, 3...12

Answer (score 0):

Dict of {str: list} might not be the best data structure for your task as you need to convert the years to ints to compare them, and there are a lot of errors you might encounter. Otherwise, you can use something like this

```py
from itertools import chain
flat = list(chain.from_iterable(d[str(year)] for year in range(year1, year2+1)))
#assuming month index starts from 1, not 0
result = sum(flat[month1 -1 : -12 + month2 or None])
```

Personally I'd use a numpy array or pandas dataframe in place of the dict.

Answer (score 0):

**You can try this:**

```
d = { 
    '1751': [70.0, 43.5, 45.3, 56.4, 60.7, 50.7, 66.3, 59.8, 23.5, 23.2, 28.5, 44.0], 
    '1752': [35.0, 50.0, 71.0, 59.3, 59.7, 39.6, 78.4, 29.3, 27.1, 46.6, 37.6, 40.0], 
    '1753': [44.0, 32.0, 45.7, 38.0, 36.0, 31.7, 22.0, 39.0, 28.0, 25.0, 20.0, 6.7], 
    '1754': [0.0, 3.0, 1.7, 13.7, 20.7, 26.7, 18.8, 12.3, 8.2, 24.1, 13.2, 4.2], 
    '1755': [10.2, 11.2, 6.8, 6.5, 0.0, 0.0, 8.6, 3.2, 17.8, 23.7, 6.8, 20.0], 
    '1756': [12.5, 7.1, 5.4, 9.4, 12.5, 12.9, 3.6, 6.4, 11.8, 14.3, 17.0, 9.4], 
    '1757': [14.1, 21.2, 26.2, 30.0, 38.1, 12.8, 25.0, 51.3, 39.7, 32.5, 64.7, 33.5], 
    '1758': [37.6, 52.0, 49.0, 72.3, 46.4, 45.0, 44.0, 38.7, 62.5, 37.7, 43.0, 43.0], 
    '1759': [48.3, 44.0, 46.8, 47.0, 49.0, 50.0, 51.0, 71.3, 77.2, 59.7, 46.3, 57.0]
}

year1 = int(input("Beginning Year: "))
month1 = int(input("Beginning Month: "))


year2 = int(input("Ending Year: "))
month2 = int(input("Ending Month: "))

total_sum = 0
for year in range(year1, year2 + 1):
    list_sum = 0
    if year == year1:
        list_sum = sum(d[str(year)][month1 -1:])
    elif year == year2:
        list_sum = sum(d[str(year)][:month2 + 1])
    else:
        list_sum = sum(d[str(year)])

    total_sum += list_sum

print(total_sum)
```

**Input and Output:**

```
Beginning Year: 1751
Beginning Month: 1
Ending Year: 1759
Ending Month: 12
3505.1999999999994
```

Answer (score 0):

No attempt here to handle your user input but here's how you could sum the values in the manner you've described:-

```
d = {
    '1751': [70.0, 43.5, 45.3, 56.4, 60.7, 50.7, 66.3, 59.8, 23.5, 23.2, 28.5, 44.0],
    '1752': [35.0, 50.0, 71.0, 59.3, 59.7, 39.6, 78.4, 29.3, 27.1, 46.6, 37.6, 40.0],
    '1753': [44.0, 32.0, 45.7, 38.0, 36.0, 31.7, 22.0, 39.0, 28.0, 25.0, 20.0, 6.7],
    '1754': [0.0, 3.0, 1.7, 13.7, 20.7, 26.7, 18.8, 12.3, 8.2, 24.1, 13.2, 4.2],
    '1755': [10.2, 11.2, 6.8, 6.5, 0.0, 0.0, 8.6, 3.2, 17.8, 23.7, 6.8, 20.0],
    '1756': [12.5, 7.1, 5.4, 9.4, 12.5, 12.9, 3.6, 6.4, 11.8, 14.3, 17.0, 9.4],
    '1757': [14.1, 21.2, 26.2, 30.0, 38.1, 12.8, 25.0, 51.3, 39.7, 32.5, 64.7, 33.5],
    '1758': [37.6, 52.0, 49.0, 72.3, 46.4, 45.0, 44.0, 38.7, 62.5, 37.7, 43.0, 43.0],
    '1759': [48.3, 44.0, 46.8, 47.0, 49.0, 50.0, 51.0, 71.3, 77.2, 59.7, 46.3, 57.0]
}

# sy -> start year, ey -> end year, sm -> start month, em -> end month
# month values are base 0 - i.e., 0-11
# specified years and months are inclusive


def doSum(sy, ey, sm, em):
    # sort the keys as the dictionary may not be sorted
    ly = sorted(list(d.keys()))
    s = 0
    try:
        for y in ly[ly.index(sy):]:
            if y > ey:
                break
            s += sum(d[y][sm:em+1])
    except Exception:
        pass
    return s


x = doSum('1752', '1754', 10, 11)
print(f'{x:.1f}')
```

Answer (score 0):

A one-liner could be like this

```
total = sum(d[year1][int(month1)-1:]+[sum(months) for months in [d[str(year)] for year in range(int(year1) + 1, int(year2))]]+d[year2][:int(month2)-1])
```

ofcourse, you have to sanitize your inputs for this.

Answer (score 0):

This might work as a starter. However, you should check if the inputs are legitimate. Also, try using clearer variable names like 'start_year' and 'end_year' instead of the opaque 'year1' and 'year2'.

```
    import numpy as np
    
    d = { 
        '1751': [70.0, 43.5, 45.3, 56.4, 60.7, 50.7, 66.3, 59.8, 23.5, 23.2, 28.5, 44.0], 
        '1752': [35.0, 50.0, 71.0, 59.3, 59.7, 39.6, 78.4, 29.3, 27.1, 46.6, 37.6, 40.0], 
        '1753': [44.0, 32.0, 45.7, 38.0, 36.0, 31.7, 22.0, 39.0, 28.0, 25.0, 20.0, 6.7], 
        '1754': [0.0, 3.0, 1.7, 13.7, 20.7, 26.7, 18.8, 12.3, 8.2, 24.1, 13.2, 4.2], 
        '1755': [10.2, 11.2, 6.8, 6.5, 0.0, 0.0, 8.6, 3.2, 17.8, 23.7, 6.8, 20.0], 
        '1756': [12.5, 7.1, 5.4, 9.4, 12.5, 12.9, 3.6, 6.4, 11.8, 14.3, 17.0, 9.4], 
        '1757': [14.1, 21.2, 26.2, 30.0, 38.1, 12.8, 25.0, 51.3, 39.7, 32.5, 64.7, 33.5], 
        '1758': [37.6, 52.0, 49.0, 72.3, 46.4, 45.0, 44.0, 38.7, 62.5, 37.7, 43.0, 43.0], 
        '1759': [48.3, 44.0, 46.8, 47.0, 49.0, 50.0, 51.0, 71.3, 77.2, 59.7, 46.3, 57.0]
         }
    
    print("Enter beginning year")
    year1 = input()
    print("Enter beginning month")
    month1 = input()
    
    
    print("Enter ending year")
    year2 = input()
    print("Enter ending month")
    month2 = input()
    
    d[year1] = d[year1][int(month1)::]
    d[year2] = d[year2][::int(month1)]
    l = np.arange(int(year1), int(year2))
    l = [str(i) for i in l]
    dtemp = {k: sum(d[k]) for k in l}
    sum_of_values = sum(dtemp.values())
    print(sum_of_values)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
d = { 
    '1751': [70.0, 43.5, 45.3, 56.4, 60.7, 50.7, 66.3, 59.8, 23.5, 23.2, 28.5, 44.0], 
    '1752': [35.0, 50.0, 71.0, 59.3, 59.7, 39.6, 78.4, 29.3, 27.1, 46.6, 37.6, 40.0], 
    '1753': [44.0, 32.0, 45.7, 38.0, 36.0, 31.7, 22.0, 39.0, 28.0, 25.0, 20.0, 6.7], 
    '1754': [0.0, 3.0, 1.7, 13.7, 20.7, 26.7, 18.8, 12.3, 8.2, 24.1, 13.2, 4.2], 
    '1755': [10.2, 11.2, 6.8, 6.5, 0.0, 0.0, 8.6, 3.2, 17.8, 23.7, 6.8, 20.0], 
    '1756': [12.5, 7.1, 5.4, 9.4, 12.5, 12.9, 3.6, 6.4, 11.8, 14.3, 17.0, 9.4], 
    '1757': [14.1, 21.2, 26.2, 30.0, 38.1, 12.8, 25.0, 51.3, 39.7, 32.5, 64.7, 33.5], 
    '1758': [37.6, 52.0, 49.0, 72.3, 46.4, 45.0, 44.0, 38.7, 62.5, 37.7, 43.0, 43.0], 
    '1759': [48.3, 44.0, 46.8, 47.0, 49.0, 50.0, 51.0, 71.3, 77.2, 59.7, 46.3, 57.0]
     }
while 1:
    year1 = int(input("Please enter a Begining year (1751 to 1759): "))
    if str(year1) not in d.keys():
        print("Sorry, your response was not loud enough.")
    else:
        #we're happy with the value given.
        #we're ready to exit the loop.
        break
while 1:
    year2 = int(input("Please enter a Ending year("+str(year1)+" to 1759): "))
    if str(year2) not in d.keys():
        print("Sorry, your response was not loud enough.")
    else:
        break
while 1:
    month1 = int(input("Please enter a Begining month (1 to 12): "))
    if month1 not in range(1,13):
        print("Sorry, your response was not loud enough.")
    else:
        break
while 1:
    month2 = int(input("Please enter a Ending month (1 to 12): "))
    if month2 not in range(1,13):
        print("Sorry, your response was not loud enough.")
    else:
        break

data_list=[]
for year in range(int(year1),int(year2)+1):
    if year==year1:
        start_month =month1
        end_month=12
    elif year==year2:
        start_month=1
        end_month=month2
    else:
        start_month=1
        end_month=12
    for i in range(start_month-1,end_month):
        data_list.append(d[str(year)][i])
print("Sum :",sum(data_list))
```

** answer is **

```
Please enter a Begining year (1751 to 1759): 1752

Please enter a Ending year(1752 to 1759): 1753

Please enter a Begining month (1 to 12): 1

Please enter a Ending month (1 to 12): 3

Sum : 695.3000000000001
```